# Gradient progress bar position

Tags: html, css

Please, how can I fill the progress block with a gradient by 50% but that the gradient would not shrink but would be static?

It needs to be like this at 50%
[image]

```css
body {
  background-color: #4158D0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(43deg, #4158D0 0%, #C850C0 46%, #FFCC70 100%);
}

#progress {
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
  border: 5px solid #000;
  background: none;
}

div {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(60, 226, 91, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 147, 0, 1) 50%, rgba(247, 3, 3, 1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="progress">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Paulie_D Can you show me an example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) CSS property paired with the [`inset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/basic-shape/inset) CSS function :

```css
body {
  background-color: #4158D0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(43deg, #4158D0 0%, #C850C0 46%, #FFCC70 100%);
}

#progress {
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
  border: 5px solid #000;
  background: none;
}

#progress div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(60, 226, 91, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 147, 0, 1) 50%, rgba(247, 3, 3, 1) 100%);
  clip-path: inset(0% 50% 0% 0%);
}
```

```html
<div id="progress">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Note that I changed the selector of your `div` rule to `#progress div`

Answer (score 2):

One element and a few calculation can also do the job

```css
.progress {
  --p: 0.5; /* progression from 0 (0%) to 1 (100%) */
  
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 5px solid #000;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(90deg, 
      rgb(247 3 3), 
      rgb(255 147 0) calc( 50%/var(--p)), 
      rgb(60 226 91) calc(100%/var(--p))
    ) 0 0/calc(var(--p)*100%) 100% no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress" style="--p: .2"></div>
<div class="progress" style="--p: .4"></div>
<div class="progress" style="--p: .6"></div>
<div class="progress" style="--p: .8"></div>
<div class="progress" style="--p: .9"></div>
<div class="progress" style="--p:  1"></div>
```

Comment: @DavidThomas it was a typo in the rgb() definition

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a solution as follows using JS by altering the percentage variable or using the clip-path CSS property

```js
    const percentage = 60
    const bgContainer = document.getElementById("bg-container")
    const bg = document.getElementById("bg")
    bg.style.width = (100 * 100 / percentage) + "%";
    bgContainer.style.width = (100 * percentage / 100) + "%";
```

```css
 body {
        background-color: #4158D0;
        background-image: linear-gradient(43deg, #4158D0 0%, #C850C0 46%, #FFCC70 100%);
    }

    #progress {
        width: 50%;
        height: 20px;
        border: 5px solid #000;
        background: none;
    }

    #bg-container {
        height: 100%;
        overflow: clip;
    }

    #bg {
        height: 100%;
        background: linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(60, 226, 91, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 147, 0, 1) 50%, rgba(247, 3, 3, 1) 100%);
    }
```

```html
<div id="progress">
        <div id="bg-container">
            <div id="bg"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```